# Make Plot Legend Wider

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a pretty plot with a legend

[image]

But I want to make the legend the same width as the graph, i.e. causing all the text to be on one line.

Code to make the legend here:

```
legend = SwatchLegend[{Blue, Orange, Red, Darker[LightGreen, 0.4], 
    Black}, {"Photoemission Signal", "Linear Fit", "Fit Begin", 
    "Fit End", "Baseline" }, LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "cmr10"}, 
   LegendMarkers -> {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[0.6], 
       Disk[]}], Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]], 
     Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]], 
     Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]], 
     Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]]}];
```

Changing the legend margins does not have the desired effects.

Comment: Look at [`LegendMarkerSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendMarkerSize.html).

Comment: That changes the size of the legend dots etc, which will change the size of the legend, but not change the width of the legend box. I like the sizes, but I want it to be same width.

Comment: Also `LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set LegendLayout:

```
legends = 
  SwatchLegend[{Blue, Orange, Red, Darker[LightGreen, 0.4], 
    Black}, {"Photoemission Signal", "Linear Fit", "Fit Begin", 
    "Fit End", "Baseline"}, LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "cmr10"}, 
   LegendMarkers -> {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[0.6], 
       Disk[]}], Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]], 
     Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]], 
     Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]], 
     Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]]}, 
   LegendLayout -> (Row[Flatten[#], Spacer[2]] &)];

ListPlot[RandomInteger[10, 20], Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[legends, Below], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]